# Can't get selected value from dropkick customised <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I've just started using [dropkick by Jamie Lottering](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick) and have my select lists transformed into customizable HTML dropdowns.  Great!  My only issue is I can't find a way to retrieve the selected value from the dropdown.

```
$('.change').dropkick({
  change: function (value, label) {
    alert('You picked: ' + label + ':' + value);
  }
});
```

The site shows the above callback example, but I can't understand how I get the value for a given id rather than have it alerted when it changes?

I want to be able to say...

```
$("#myselect").val()
```

Comment: Isn't the `value` argument exactly what you want? (Or, in other words: what do you want to do with the value?)

Comment: Thanks Diode and PPvG for your responses.  I think my dilemma is that on page load it displays my select and then gets styled by dropkick.   But then through an ajax file I want to update the options.  Either by changing the selected one or existing ones and adding additional ones.  I'm not sure the best way to do this?  Should I recreate the select and options and then format again using dropkick or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question.

Suppose I have 2 select elements

```
<select id="select1" class="my-select">
   <option>....</option>
   <option>....</option>
   <option>....</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="my-select">
   <option>....</option>
   <option>....</option>
   <option>....</option>
</select>
```

I can style them using

```
$(".my-select").dropkick();
```

and get values using

```
$("#select1").val();
$("#select2").val();
```

.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I've thought about it more I think my question is that after the select has been styled using dropkick what is the best way of changing the selected option of the dropdown or existing options and adding additional ones. Should I recreate the select and options and then format again using dropkick or is there a better way?

Comment: Ya that is what you have to do. Modify select content and call **.dropkick()** again.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Always good to know the right way to do it!